# PowerBI Query contains transformations that can't be used for DirectQuery

Tags: powerbi

I am using PowerBI Desktop (2.96.1061.0) to connect to a local MS SQL server so I can prepare some visualizations. It is important to mention that **all data connections** (Tables, SQL queries) **are using the DirectQuery** option.

It's been quite a smooth experience so far. No issues at all. Now I am trying to get some new data, again, through a direct SQL query:

```
SELECT BillId, string_agg(PGroupName, ', ')
FROM
 (SELECT bm.ImportedBillsId as BillId, pg.Name as PGroupName
  FROM [BillMp] bm 
    JOIN [Mps] m on bm.ImportersId = m.Id
    JOIN [PGroups] pg on m.PoliticalGroupId = pg.Id
  GROUP BY bm.ImportedBillsId, pg.Name) t
GROUP BY BillId
```

but for some reason, it is not letting me re-create the model and apply the new changes. No matter that the import wizard is able to visualize the actual data prior to the update. This is the error that I am getting:

[image]

I have also tried to import only the data from the internal/nested query

```
SELECT bm.ImportedBillsId as BillId, pg.Name as PGroupName
      FROM [BillMp] bm 
        JOIN [Mps] m on bm.ImportersId = m.Id
        JOIN [PGroups] pg on m.PoliticalGroupId = pg.Id
      GROUP BY bm.ImportedBillsId, pg.Name
```

and process (according to [this](https://exceltown.com/en/tutorials/power-bi/powerbi-com-and-power-bi-desktop/power-bi-data-sources/group-by-to-merge-texts-something-like-concatenatex-but-in-queries/) article) the other/outer query through PowerBI but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: It will be good to know what is the change from previous query. if the previous queries was working and you needed the updated data. It would have came automatically since its a direct query. Did you do any changes to the direct Query statement from before running one??

Comment: also can you just remove the second JOIN statement (JOIN [PGroups] pg on m.PoliticalGroupId = pg.Id) and then try